# Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <file:03c53983-5dda-4e91-bdab-a36ca35454e8> while in state root.deleted.saved

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple Ember.js application and have to model a folder structure (a folder has files as children).

The error occurs if I delete a file from a folder, restore it and try to reload the folder from the server. The id of the file does not change on restore and it looks like the deleted file is still present in the store identity map when I try to reload the parent folder.

The code used to reload the folder is below:

```
reloadFolder(folderId) {
    return this.get("store").findRecord("folder", folderId, {
       reload: true
    });
}
```

The error I get is

```
Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <file:03c53983-5dda-4e91-bdab-a36ca35454e8> while in state root.deleted.saved.
```

What could be the cause of this problem?

Version for the libraries:

Ember: 2.13.0
Ember Data: 2.13.0